# Targeting PHP function output with CSS

Tags: php, css

I've got a shopping cart application and I want to add a miniaturized version of the cart to my home page. The shopping cart is the page 'modcart.php' and I've included it in my homepage simply by doing this:

```
function miniCart(){
  ob_start();
  include('modcart.php');
  $page = ob_get_clean();
  return $page;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? If not, how do I now target the output of this function in my CSS?

Comment: That entirely depends on the html generated by the function.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the HTML and CSS is set up in your `modcard.php` page, you could try to do some sort of pattern replacement to modify the IDs or classes being used. However it would probably be simplest - in a case such as this one - to just alter the output of the PHP script based on a value set before the include.

For instance, if you were to change your `miniCart` function to do something like:

```
function miniCart($page='default'){
    ob_start();
    include('modcart.php');
    $page = ob_get_clean();
    return $page;
}
```

You could then alter what happens inside `modcard.php` based on the `$page` variable. If your code properly separates the HTML and CSS styles into actual CSS stylesheets, then it would be a simple matter of switching which stylesheet is loaded, based on the value:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="modcart-<?php echo isset($page) ? $page : "default"; ?>.css">
```

However if you use HTML style tags or inline CSS, this would not be a hugely efficient method.